# Is there a way to launch uTorrent and not display the GUI window?

Tags: launchd

Since uTorrent to my best of knowledge doesen't support a daemon/server mode, I would like to add it to launchd to start upon login (and restart after a potential crash), **but without the app window opening**.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try saving a plist like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/utorrent.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>utorrent</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>open</string>
        <string>-gjWa</string>
        <string>uTorrent</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It can be loaded with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/utorrent.plist` or by logging out and back in.

```
  -W, --wait-apps   Blocks until the used applications are closed (even if they were already running).
  -j, --hide        Launches the app hidden.
  -g, --background  Does not bring the application to the foreground.
```

`/Applications/uTorrent.app/Contents/MacOS/uTorrent` would display a visible uTorrent window if uTorrent wasn't already running.

Another option might be to add a line like this to crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * pgrep -xq uTorrent && osascript -e 'launch app "uTorrent"' || open -gja uTorrent
```

`open -gj` shows the main window if uTorrent is open but has no visible windows. `launch` shows the main window if uTorrent is not open.

Programs run from crontab are run in the system security / login session. For example Mail can't access keychains if it is opened by cron.

Comment: I have no problems creating the plist file. In fact it is already running. My problem is the GUI window, which auto-opens upon launch and there seems to be no app-pref setting to prevent it from doing so. My core question was, if there is way to open the app without the window opening.

Comment: Way to go...... Lauri :)

Comment: The altered plist works like a charm! Thank you! I have one more question: **Is this correct:** the -Wa flag prevents launched to launch the app, if it is already running, effectively preventing the app to run twice?

Comment: ...I have been checking out the [manpage for **open**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html), but it dosen't mention your -j flag.

Comment: -W blocks the open command until uTorrent is terminated, so that launchd runs the open command again if uTorrent is terminated. -j was added in 10.8, and it is only shown in the help message.